# Populate a listview from a database column whithout repeating values

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, listview

I wanted to know if it is possible to fill a listview excluding repeated words:

I am building an app that stores various information about people (name, age, ...).

On one of the columns I want to store the person country (the input is a textView->String), so each person can write the country and I don't have to hardcode them.

The database can later be read and as a selection, I want to list the countries so when you choose one, the people from that country show up.

The thing is that if I just fill up the list from the column, countries will show multiple times repeating and that is what I want to avoid.

All country inputs would be sequential so at first, I thought about making tables named after the country input and load them by table name but I don't know if this would be possible either.

I am working on Android Studio and handling the database via `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just have to pick an appropriate data structure as far as I have understood your question. You need a [`Set`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-in-java/) there to populate the list of countries in your case.

`Set` is like an `ArrayList` which automatically manages the uniqueness of its keys. I think this will solve your problem.

I am just placing the example from the tutorial mentioned above for convenience.

```
// Java code for adding elements in Set
import java.util.*;
public class Set_example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Set deonstration using HashSet
        Set<String> hash_Set = new HashSet<String>();
        hash_Set.add("Geeks");
        hash_Set.add("For");
        hash_Set.add("Geeks");
        hash_Set.add("Example");
        hash_Set.add("Set");
        System.out.print("Set output without the duplicates");

        System.out.println(hash_Set);

        // Set deonstration using TreeSet
        System.out.print("Sorted Set after passing into TreeSet");
        Set<String> tree_Set = new TreeSet<String>(hash_Set);
        System.out.println(tree_Set);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would to derive a list of the **DISTINCT** countries e.g. :-

```
SELECT DISTINCT _country FROM people;
```

- Note, this is based upon the people table as below.

You could have a secondary table of countries into which countries are automatically added using a trigger.

As an example the following SQL demonstrates this :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS country;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS add_country;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (_name TEXT, _country TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS country (_country TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS add_country AFTER INSERT ON people
    BEGIN 
            INSERT OR IGNORE INTO country VALUES(new._country);
      END;
INSERT INTO people VALUES 
    ('Fred','England'),
    ('Tom','Australia'),
    ('Mary','New Zealand'),
    ('Zoe','France'),
    ('Sarah','England'),
    ('Howard','New Zealand'),
    ('Anne','England');
SELECT * FROM country;
```

- The three DROP statements are just for testing purposes.
- The first CREATE TABLE statement creates the core, **people** table.
- The second CREATE TABLE statement creates the complimentary **country** table.

  - Note that the column for storing the country has the **UNIQUE** constraint so a value cannot be duplicated.
- The CREATE TRIGGER statement creates a trigger so that when a row is inserted into the people table an attempt is made to insert a row with the provided country into the country table.

  - Note the INSERT OR IGNORE ignore the failure should the UNQIUE constraint occur.
- The INSERT INTO statement adds a number of rows into the people table (and thus into the country table according to the trigger).
- The SELECT statement list's the countries as per :-

[image]

You could use a QUERY to then extract the people from a selected country based upon the country table being the source for the selection list e.g. say the 3rd country was selected then the following QUERY :-

```
SELECT _name FROM people WHERE _country = (SELECT _country FROM country WHERE rowid = 3); -- 3rd country
```

Would result in :-
[image]

- Note you wouldn't utilise the rowid as there is no guarantee that it monotonically increases. Rather, you'd either use the country name directly, or utilise an alias for the rowid.

  - The rowid was used to clearly demonstrate that the country table was being used in the WHERE clause, via the SUB QUERY.

---

**However**, both the above solutions contravene normalisation as the **country** will be duplicated.

Although a little more complex adding an alias for the rowid (`_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` to the country table) allows a reference to the country. The method explained below also takes advantage of the flexibility of SQLite columns types and that any column type can store any value, and still assuming that you want the **country** to be input rather than selected then the following would substitute the input country for the reference to the country table if it exists or not, still automatically inserting a new **country**.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS country;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS add_country;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, _name TEXT, _country TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS country (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, _country TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS add_country AFTER INSERT ON people
    BEGIN 
        INSERT OR IGNORE INTO country 
                    VALUES(null,new._country);
              UPDATE people 
                    SET _country = (
                            SELECT _id FROM country WHERE _country = new._country
                        ) 
                        WHERE _country = new._country 
                        AND _name = new._name;
    END;
INSERT INTO people VALUES 
    (null,'Fred','England'),
    (null,'Tom','Australia'),
    (null,'Mary','New Zealand'),
    (null,'Zoe','France'),
    (null,'Sarah','England'),
    (null,'Howard','New Zealand'),
    (null,'Anne','England');
SELECT * FROM country; 
SELECT * FROM people;
```

. There are two important changes/factors:-

1. The **country** table includes a new column **_id** which is an alias of the rowid
2. The TRIGGER includes two actions

   1. The original insert (with null for the _id column so a unique id is automatically generated)
   2. AN UPDATE which will substitute the country column that was input with the **_id** of the respective country thus referencing the country by it's id and thus doing away with the duplicated country.

The Results from the above are :-

The **country** table  (`SELECT * FROM country;`):-

[image]

The **people** table (`SELECT * FROM people;`):-

[image]

- The **_country** column of the **people** table references the **_id** column of the country, even though the original input was the ***country***.

Of course country 1,2,3 means nothing to an end user so to get the name and country for presentation purposes you use something like :-

```
SELECT _name, country._country 
FROM people JOIN country ON people._country = country._id;
```

Which would result in :-

[image]

---

**Note**; none of these solutions take into consideration that a country may be misspelt. Hence why a pre-defined list of countries would really be the recommended solution.